# Lwjgl how to simplify heightmap to get higher fps?

Tags: java, math, optimization, lwjgl, heightmap

I'm a little bit disappointed about the fps of my game. I am still at the beginning of the development of the game. When I started my game first, I got around 350 fps. After I added a heightmap and some more code to the program, is it logical that the fps drop. Now I got 39 fps.
I'm still at the beginning and the fps is already low. I wonder what happens when I finish the project, I think the fps will be so low that it's irritating.
I know that I'm asking very much of the program, the heightmap is the big problem.
The map has an area of 200 * 200 vertices, each vertice has a height.
200 * 200 = 40000 vertices, each frame.
I was thinking to simplify the map. My idea is to create a method which simplifies the whole heightmap. Each 4 vertices belong to a quad. When there are two or more quads next to each other which have the same height on each vertex, they can be merged to one quad.
The point is that there should be less vertices. (I think)

I will show some example code of my heightmap.

```
package rgc.area;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HeightMap {

    public int width;  // Vertices (width)
    public int height; // Vertices (height)

    public List<Float> map = new ArrayList<Float>();

    /**
     * 
     * @param width The width of the map (x-axis)
     * @param height The height of the map (z-axiz, NOT y-axis);
     */
    public HeightMap(int width, int height) {

        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        for(int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {

            map.add(1.0f);
        }
    }

    public Dimension getSize() {

        return new Dimension(this.width, this.height);
    }

    public int getWidth() {

        return this.width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {

        return this.height;
    }

    /**
    * Set the height of a vertex of the map
    */
    public void setHeight(int x, int y, float h) {

        int index = x;

        if(y > 0) {

            index += (y - 1) * width;
        }

        map.set(index - 1, h);

        /* DEBUG
        for(int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++) {

            System.out.println(i + "   height: " + map.get(i));
        }
        */
    }

    public float getHeight(int x, int y) {

        int index = x;

        if(y > 0) {

            index += (y - 1) * width;
        }

        return map.get(index);
    }

    public float getHeight(float x, float y) {

        return this.getHeight((int)x, (int)y);
    }

    /**
     * This method simplifies the heightmap.
     * It will merge seperate quads with the same vertex heights.
     * This is to save memory and render faster.
     * 
     * This method should only be called when the heightmap is changed.
     * So this method should NOT be called every frame.
     */
    public void simplify() {

            // Don't really know how to do this.
        for(int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {

            for(int w = 1; w < width - 1; w++) {

                if(map.get(i) == map.get(i + w)) {


                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Has anyone experience with this?
Are there any ideas or improvements, and is the way I do it correctly?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can get some more help [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Well. That's a height map. The important thing ist: How are you *rendering* it? 40k vertices should be hardly noticable on a modern graphics card. But if there is something involved like `glVertex3f(x,y,map.getHeight(x,y))` then I can imagine that this is horribly slow. (BTW: A noticable improvement could already be achieved by replacing the `List<Float>` with a simple `float[]` array, but for real high performance, you should consider Vertex Buffer Objects (VBO) and the other "modern" OpenGL stuff)

Comment: Use a VBO. That will help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should us a fixed array instead of a list. This will give a small boost already. I don't see a function to resize your heightmap, so it is probably fixed size anyway. You could initialize a static array that way:

```
float[][] map;
public HeightMap(int width, int height) {
    this.map = new float[width][height];
    ...
}
```

Using a two dimensional array would also simplify your getHeight(x, y) and setHeihgt(x, y, height) methods. Other than that it highly depends on your render method. I recommend using vertex buffer objects with GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP for heightmaps.
For more information on vertex buffer objects, check http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Using_Vertex_Buffer_Objects_%28VBO%29
Other than that try using cull facing. This might boost your performance even further.
Also you might want to set a render distance for larger levels to improve performance.
I know, this is probably not the answer you was looking for, but I hope it will help though.
Edit:
Oh, it seems you are using quads. One thing I did for heightmaps was, I assigned a vertex for each pixel and connect them using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP (as suggested above). Other than that you can still use QUADS, I think it won't make any difference at all. If you follow the suggestions above, you can probably get a 1000*1000 heightmap running with 200 FPS. (That's what I am currently having on one project).